# Listbox doesn't update after adding new items to it

Tags: wpf, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a list box that is bound to an Observable Collection , when I the user add any new items to it it doesn't update itself until the app is closed and opened again.

(I serializes the content of the item source of this list and store it in Isolated Storage)

The only possible solution until now is to set the item source after adding the item in every method that allow the user to add any item but this isn't possible while adding from other pages as I can't access UI elements directly. Any help ?

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it ! In the Deserialize method I was pointing to another list (the one that has the result to Deserialization) and that damaged the binding.